# Preventing Application Freeze During User Input in Lazarus Python Script

Tags: python, freepascal, lazarus

I have a Python script that asks for user input:

Python File:

```
confirmation = input("Enter confirmation (Y/S): ")
```

LFM File:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 250
  Height = 240
  Top = 113
  Width = 320
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 240
  ClientWidth = 320
  LCLVersion = '3.0.0.2'
  object mOutPut: TMemo
    Left = 8
    Height = 170
    Top = 64
    Width = 304
    Color = clBlack
    Font.CharSet = ANSI_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWhite
    Font.Height = -13
    Font.Name = 'Consolas'
    Font.Pitch = fpFixed
    Font.Quality = fqDraft
    Lines.Strings = (
      'moutput'
    )
    ParentFont = False
    ReadOnly = True
    ScrollBars = ssAutoBoth
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 111
    Height = 25
    Top = 20
    Width = 75
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object PythonEngine1: TPythonEngine
    IO = PythonGUIInputOutput1
    Left = 224
    Top = 19
  end
  object PythonGUIInputOutput1: TPythonGUIInputOutput
    DelayWrites = True
    UnicodeIO = True
    RawOutput = True
    Output = mOutPut
    Left = 48
    Top = 19
  end
end
```

PAS File:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
   Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
     PythonEngine, PythonGUIInputOutput, Process;

type

     { TForm1 }

   TForm1 = class(TForm)
            Button1: TButton;
            mOutPut: TMemo;
            PythonEngine1: TPythonEngine;
            PythonGUIInputOutput1: TPythonGUIInputOutput;
            procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      procedure ExecutePY;
   private

   public

   end;

var
   Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: tstringlist;
begin
 //ExecutePY;
  s := TStringList.Create;
  try
     s.LoadFromFile('input.py');
     pythonengine1.execstrings(s);
  finally
     s.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

In a program written with the Lazarus IDE I inserted the TPythonEngine and TPythonGUIInputOutput components from the PythonForLazarus component library.

TPythonEngine.IO is pointing to TPythonGUIInput and this in turn has TPythonGUIInput.Output pointing to a Memo. When I run the Python script using `TPythonEngine.ExecStrings(TListStrings)`, in the user input part, the Lazarus InputQuery is displayed for the user to enter the option but the application is frozen waiting for the user input, that is, the InputQuery (box ) freezes the application until the user enters the value. How do I ensure that the user can continue using the application window before entering data into InputQuery?

Before, I needed to display the Python Input data input graphically in the Lazarus application and the PythonGUIInputOutput from the PythonForLazarus library made it possible to execute the script and display the input box, but the application is stuck waiting for user input.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please add the content of your ``lfm`` and ``pas`` files to your question

Comment: Why do you use a Python inputbox instead of a native pascal one?

Comment: TPythonInputOutput itself displays the inputbox, is there a way to change this, use the lazarus inputbox?